# Log4net used in Windsor with locking Model

Tags: locking, log4net, windsor-facilities

Do I need to use locking model when use log4net from windsor logging facility and fileappender?
 Or this issue is resolved by windsor itself?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that using generated proxy class this is impossible. Pity.